# How to get Value of First different number in reverse order?

Tags: excel

[image]

Wanted to find the first different number in reverse order:
as per image wanted to find the last different number in reverse order Ex: -
I lookup at the end from 10: then it should retrieve last diff no i.e 20, similarly at 20 it should retrieve 15

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)-(ROWS($1:1)-1))
```

and copy downwards. *(this reverses column **A**)*

In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,B:B<>B1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but here the challange was not to add additional row, since the data is too large. anyways got the solution by modifying some parameters with the solution provided by you: - :)

=INDEX(A2:A17,XMATCH(TRUE,A2:A17<>A17,,-1))

Comment: @VasantaKoli  GOOD JOB!  Your answer is better than mine, taking advantage of `XMATCH()`

Answer (score 1):

You can compare all the values in the range to the last value and get an internal array of 0's and 1's. Then, from that array, you can find the position of the last 1. The position will be the position of the value you need to get.

`=INDEX(A1:A16,MATCH(1,A1:A16<>A16))`